# Rspec test Comparable <=>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking, stub

I have a model that uses `Comparable` and I have implemented the required `<=>` method for this. How should I go about testing this w/ `rspec` (I know this isn't TDD since I've already implemented the method)?

```
class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Comparable
  def <=>(other)
    self.sort_key <=> other.sort_key
  end
end
```

Comment: I wouldn't beat yourself up for writing such a trivial method before writing your tests. The important thing is to have tests, not necessarily how you arrived at them.

Comment: Even if it's trivial I would still like to see how people would to about testing it as I'm a novice when it comes to testing.

Comment: What I mean is you wrote a method, it's not a big deal, unlike say, writing a large application and *then* trying to go about writing tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following `Grade` implementation:

```
class Grade
  attr_reader :sort_key
  def initialize(sort_key)
    @sort_key = sort_key
  end
  def <=>(other)
    return nil unless other.respond_to?(:sort_key)
    @sort_key <=> other.sort_key
  end
end
```

I'd just test that `Grade#<=>` behaves properly, according to what the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) for `Object#<=>` says:

```
# comparable_grade.spec
describe "Grade#<=>" do

  it "returns 0 when both operands are equal" do
    (Grade.new(0) <=> Grade.new(0)).should eq(0)
  end

  it "returns -1 when first operand is lesser than second" do
    (Grade.new(0) <=> Grade.new(1)).should eq(-1)
  end

  it "returns 1 when first operand is greater than second" do
    (Grade.new(1) <=> Grade.new(0)).should eq(1)
  end

  it "returns nil when operands can't be compared" do
    (Grade.new(0) <=> Grade.new("foo")).should be(nil)
    (Grade.new(0) <=> "foo").should be(nil)
    (Grade.new(0) <=> nil).should be(nil)
  end

  it "can compare a Grade with anything that respond_to? :sort_key" do
    other = double(sort_key: 0)
    (Grade.new(0) <=> other).should eq(0)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use stub to test. Fast and easy.

```
describe Grade do
  context "<=>" do
    before do
      g1 = Grade.new
      g2 = Grade.new
      g3 = Grade.new
      g1.stub(:sort_key=>1)
      g2.stub(:sort_key=>2)
      g3.stub(:sort_key=>1)
    end

    it "calls sort_key" do
      Grade.any_instance.should_receive(:sort_key)
      g1 < g2
    end

    it "works for comparing" do
      expect{g1<g2}.to be_true
      expect{g2>g1}.to be_true
      expect{g1=g3}.to be_true
    end
  end
end
```